# Python Tkinter Window not closing

Tags: python, tkinter, window

So I was writing a short code to test something when I noticed this interesting behaviour.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

master=tkinter.Tk()
master.geometry("800x850+0+0")
master.configure(background="lightblue")

def d():
    master.destroy()

button=Button(master, text="asdf", command=d).pack()

master.mainloop()
```

The button closes the window as expected, but when I click on the red button on the top left button (from the actual window, not tkinter), the program gets stuck and doesn't respond. 
However, when I change the code to remove the text in the button as follows:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

master=tkinter.Tk()
master.geometry("800x850+0+0")
master.configure(background="lightblue")

def d():
    master.destroy()

button=Button(master, command=d).pack()

master.mainloop()
```

It now works perfectly fine. Both the tkinter button in the window and the red button from the actual window close the window as expected.
Why does this happen?
I am using python 3.5 on Mac, in case this matters.

Comment: Just a hunch, but what happens if you split the lines into: `button=Button(master, text="asdf", command=d)` and next line: `button.pack()`? It should work fine though, and so it does on my system (Ubuntu 16.04)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it out on some of my friends computers and they didn't have this issue, so it appears that it was just a hardware specific problem.