# Can't finish process after pressing exit button on tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, process

my problem is that I have a GUI made in tkinter that plots some maps and info and that part works good, but when I try to close the program with the X button of the window, the process is still running and I have to kill the process with the stop button, as read [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14838635/quit-mainloop-in-python) they recommend to run in CMD, I did it on windows and check the task manager and after closing the program the process still continued, what can i do to fix that?
Here is the structure of the script:

```
#This is some figure where i plot the maps
#marco de imagen principal
f = plt.figure(figsize=(3,3))
axe = f.add_subplot(111)
#axe = f.add_subplot(111)
#plt.axis('off')
axe.format_coord = lambda x, y: ''

#marco de ploteo de mapa
figu=plt.Figure(figsize=(2,2))
#ploteo=figu.add_subplot(111)
ploteo=figu.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
ploteo.format_coord = lambda x, y: ''
plt.axis('off')


Class Inicio(tk.Tk):
     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
     #I initialize all the menu, labels, variables and canvas and some other functions

     def libro(self):

     def onpress(self,event):
     .
     .
     .
     and more funtions


ex = Inicio()
ex.geometry("1280x720")

ex.mainloop()
```

Maybe the problem has to do with the plot?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue on Windows 7, Python 2.7. Maybe the problem is due to something in your 'Inicio' class. Or it could be a hardware specific bug?
 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39601107/python-tkinter-window-not-closing)

Comment: mmm I don't think is an specific bug, I already tried on Ubuntu and Windows and the problem still continues. thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried including a protocol to handle closing on the `X` button?

```
import tkMessageBox as tmb

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # All your stuff
    self.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.close_app)

def close_app(self):
    if tmb.askokcancel("Close", "Are you sure...?"):
        self.destroy()
```

This assumes that `self.destroy()` is applied to your `root` TKinter frame via `ex.mainloop()` since it is your outermost call. `self.destroy()` on the frame created by `ex.mainloop()` will end the `mainloop()` for `root` as well.

Comment: Thanks, I followed your instructions but still process continue on background, but then I changed the 'self.destroy()' by 'exit()' and worked perfectly!

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkMessageBox'

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when usign Tkinter and matplotlib, what worked for me was to add

```py
fig = plt.figure()
plt.close() # add this line of code
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
```

I suppose that when creating plt.figure() in the background a tk window is created that you cannot see therefore the python script is never ended.